# download in spring mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spring, download

I have an application which has to download from a different domain.Once the download is completed the control should return to my application and refresh that page.All this is in SPring MVC application.Please help me in doing that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write all the code for you, but this is what I'd do.

From your front end code, call a SpringMVC servlet.
From that servlet (or server side if you want to keep your controller code clean), do a CURL request to the different domain and download the file.
Do whatever you need to do to the file, store it, persist it, whatever.
Use SpringMVC to do a page refresh as the response from the servlet.

This will get around any cross domain javascript concerns.